# Java arraylist find missing fields using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this below code.
Two sets of arraylist.
How do I use streams to iterate and compare itemlist_a and itemlist_b to detect that c and d is missing in itemlist_b?
Of course I can use the traditional for loop, but is there a different way to achieve using streams or something else?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    class item {
        String name;

    public item(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<item> itemlist_a = new ArrayList<item>();
        itemlist_a.add(new item("a"));
        itemlist_a.add(new item("b"));

        List<item> itemlist_b = new ArrayList<item>();
        itemlist_b.add(new item("a"));
        itemlist_b.add(new item("b"));
        itemlist_b.add(new item("c"));
        itemlist_b.add(new item("d"));
    }
}
```

Comment: `itemlist_b.removeIf(b -> itemlist_a.stream().anyMatch(a -> a.name.equals(b.name)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Java List API**
copy of one list and then remove all the elements common with the other

```
List<Item> differences = new ArrayList<>(itemlist_b);
differences.removeAll(itemlist_a);
```

**Streams API**

```
List<Item> differences = itemlist_b.stream()
            .filter(element -> !itemlist_a.contains(element))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**[Google Guava](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html)**

```
List<Item> differences = new ArrayList<>(Sets.difference(Sets.newHashSet(itemlist_a), Sets.newHashSet(itemlist_b)));
```

**[Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/)**

```
List<Item> differences = new ArrayList<>((CollectionUtils.removeAll(itemlist_b, itemlist_a)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good application for streams, but you could do it like this:

```
itemlist_a.stream().filter(e -> !itemlist_b.contains(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will give you a list of all items which are in itemlist_a but not in itemlist_b.
However streams are designed for functional programming which means that they should not rely on variables outside the stream. In this case itemlist_b is not in the stream but does influence the outcome of the function. It will work however.

Comment: Only if `item` implements `equals()`.

Comment: *they should not rely on variables outside the stream* sounds like an overly strict interpretation of [statelessness](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness). As long as the variable isn't changing state, there's nothing wrong with referencing it in a stream.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to override `equals` and `hashCode` in Item, then use `removeAll` on the superset to retain the difference:

```
//the Item class
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // TODO
    return Objects.hashCode(name);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // TODO: implement
    return this.name.equals(((item) obj).name);
}
```

Then you can get the difference:

```
itemlist_b.removeAll(itemlist_a);
```

What will be left in `itemlist_b` after that call will be the difference. If you want `itemlist_b` to be unchanged, you can do the same thing using a copy

```
List<Item> diff = new ArrayList<>(itemlist_b);
diff.removeAll(itemlist_a);
```

And you have the difference in `diff`.

---

Since you're using lists, you just need to pay attention to your business logic with respect to duplicates. `removeAll` will remove all matching elements.